# Laravel relation has many with comma seprated

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get a relation, here is my code:

**OrderController.php**

```
public function orders()
    {
        $orders = Order::with('packages')->OrderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate();
        return view('admin/orders/orders')->with(compact('orders'));
    }
```

**Order.php**

```
function packages(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Package', 'id','cart_items');
}
```

but the problem is `cart_items` contains a value like this (5,6) comma separated, how can I get relation hasMany from array?

Comment: kindly add more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its's not possible by ORM need to work with mutator and accessor. Please remove packages method and try this in your Order model;

```
protected $appends = ['packages'];

public function getPackagesAttribute ()
{
    if ($this->cart_items) {
        $cart_items = explode(',', $this->cart_items);
        if(count($cart_items)>0) {
            return Package::whereIn('id', $cart_items)->get();
        }
    } return null;
}
```